# Как из Sheets писать данные в GoogleCloudSQL и наоборот?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-cloud

Собственно вопрос в названии темы. Как это сделать средствами Google Script?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос так, чтобы он описывал конкретную проблему с достаточной детализацией для определения адекватного ответа. См. правила.

Answer (score 0):

Обратитесь к документации - там подробно все описано.

Конкретнее - к [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc)

> This service allows scripts to connect to JDBC-compliant databases,
>   including **Google Cloud SQL**, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, and Oracle

Comment: Сергей, спасибо! Видел эту но понять не могу. нет ли у вас хорошего примера с объяснением как это делать, желательно на русском?

Comment: Вот официальный гайд (на англ) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc . В поисковике еще можно найти. На русском не встречал. Попробуйте автопереводчики сайтов. (google translate)

Answer (score -1):

Все оказалось очень просто средствами php, здесь описано: https://codd-wd.ru/primery-google-sheets-tablicy-api-php/ . Описание текущей библиотеки.
А вот здесь описано для библиотеки, которая не поддерживается, но она рабочая, я проверил. Здесь очень понятное описание для чайников. И главное, здесь описано решение проблемы ошибки, связанной с предоставлением права доступа именно к этому файлу: https://youtu.be/MfhvNHY55cQ

Comment: Но вопрос был  "...Как это сделать средствами Google Script?". А так есть решения и на Java и на Python и на чем угодно еще.

Comment: Я смог это сделать из php (для меня это было кривым решением), из GAS  у меня так и не получилось.